# Could the inputs of the Perceptron training algorithm be had different types?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification, perceptron

Have to have the inputs in the Perceptron training algorithm the same type?

i.e Could one input be had a boolean type and another input be had integer type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They cannot be arbitrary.  Look at the calculation steps and termination condition (convergence criterion):

```
Update:
y[j](t) = f[w(t) ⋅ x[j] ] 
        = f[w[0](t) x[j,0] + w[1](t) x[j,1] + ⋯ + w[n](t) x[j,n] ]

Convergence:
error = sum(abs(d[j] - y[j](t) )for all j) 
error / j_max < epsilon
```

This requires that you have at least a partially-ordered data type with defined dot-product with your weight type, (usually multiplication with the weight type and addition on the product type), subtraction for the error computation, and some valid convergence value *epsilon*.

I strongly recommend that you stick with real (float or double) weights.  Your input *could* be of another type if you're properly formal about the operations, but it's a bit tricky in practice: can you define that dot-product on your input and weight vector?  For string input, what is

```
"hello" ⋅ [0.66, 0.21, -1.13]
```

More generally, how do you store an evaluation vector in your perceptron and then measure how well it matches the input?  How do you adjust the vector in back-propagation?

If you can manage those, you can handle your input type.

Personally, I recommend that you stick with the first suggestion: map your inputs to numbers if you can.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with your recommendation. Most things can be embedded -- best to work with those embeddings.

Comment: Right.  We already have those properties in numbers.  However, spelling correction does work on string similarities; it's possible to train such a beast.

Answer (score 1):

It is based on which library you are using for building it. In general all neural networks have just one type of input - decimals. Nothing else is supported from theoretical point of view. What all libraries do under the hood is convert any other data type to decimal input. Strings are converted via dictionaries, booleans - just to 0 and 1 (or -1 and 1) etc.